# Why is it wrong to use chillax?

Tags: word-usage

I marked a student down for using the word *chillax* as I believed it to not be a word. Later on they approach me on the issue and show me that it is indeed in the dictionary.

Every fiber of my being screams that it shouldn't be used. Even this site underlines the word saying it's not correct.

According to all dictionary entries I've seen it's not even listed as slang, only informal.

**What is a valid reason that *chillax* shouldn't be used?**

Perhaps because it's informal but that doesn't seem like a valid reason as there are plenty of informal words that are quite common and I wouldn't think to mark them down for words such as phone or kids.

Comment: This site does not mark *chillax* as incorrect, as far as I can see. My spellchecker does, but that's because spellcheckers are behind the times.

Comment: Robusto's answer is spot on. While you may be able to find some argument based on context, most likely the usage is fine. Use your mistake as a lesson opportunity.

Comment: Presumably this was not a math assignment: "Can I split *x* into two factors? Chillax, Dude!  *x* is not a prime number!"

Comment: You're not alone...I hate the word too...and I'm unrepentant on this.  I don't know why, there's just something about it that grinds my gears.  I agree with Robusto...its a matter of appropriateness.  What was the topic for writing?

Comment: Note that the word is incredibly "young".  [One online dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chillax) records it's first known use as 1999.  As such, even in the best of circumstances it must be considered "slang" -- appropriate only in text that is attempting to reproduce vernacular speech.

Comment: The other online dictionary which lists it, [Am. Heritage 5th edition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chillax), actually does expressly mark it as slang. It's not even in the 4th, assuming Wordnik's coverage of that Editon is comprehensive. I only seem to recall seeing this word occasionally used on T.V. and usually as a part of a characterization of the phrases "just chill" or "just relax". I can not think of any "reason" to absolutely avoid using it though, since anybody unfamiliar with  the word should be able to quickly deduce the meaning if they know those rather familiar phrases...

Comment: My take on this: It depends on context. Just like any other use of informal or slang words. The question doesn't really give the context of the usage, so it's very hard to judge.

Comment: This is not an objective question about how English works. It is a request for support for a particular opinion -- that is, the asker already knows the answer he wants. That kind of question tends to attract rants -- which has now happened. See our help center, especially "What types of questions should I avoid asking". Can you reword to be objective?

Answer (score 10):

Language changes over time. New words are added and old ones fall by the wayside. The portmanteau *chillax* (combining *chill*, from "chill out," a newish slang term meaning "relax," and *relax* meaning the same thing) is an example of how a lot of people talk these days.

What you may want to think about is when such a term is appropriate and when it is not. In an academic or scientific paper (excluding linguistics) one would do well to avoid the term altogether; the same applies to legal documents, sober-sided business publications, and so on.

Bear in mind that if your student tells you to "chillax" it's fairly rude, so that is also a case where you might want to suggest it not be used. But you needn't worry that casual use of *chillax* among peers will rot the students' brains. It won't.

Wallace Stevens, the great American poet, said of modern poetry that "It has to be living, to learn the speech of the place." "Chillax" is an example of living language. Do not feel you have to kill it, because 1) you don't have to, and 2) you can't.