# When was the word "chillax" first used?

Tags: etymology

When was the word "chillax" first used? I'm sure it would have risen from TV or movies.

Comment: I'm sure TV or movies picked it up from preexisting slang, to (attempt to) emulate whatever subculture the work was representing. The slang invented on/for/by media rarely has much staying power.

Comment: A [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273084/) on a (very closely) related earlier question cites [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chillax) as saying first known use is 1999. I doubt if it's meaningful / reliable to attempt to single out who was "most responsible" for popularising it, since I'm sure it would already have been abortively coined many times before that.

Comment: Actually, it's from the axe made of ice that a caveman used to kill a woolly mammoth around 10,000 BC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.it/books?id=h0mcBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=chillax%201989&source=bl&ots=_JyOV0qQ2i&sig=9XFj0OS5OhhncvEYDLiyXqldEFo&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwnZD8s9bPAhWEWRQKHQFMAY0Q6AEIHjAB#v=onepage&q=chillax%201989&f=false):

> - ***chillax*** verb ***to calm down and relax US,  1993***

The following source says that it dates back to at least 1996:

***[Chillax](http://behindthegrammar.com/2010/07/top-10-made-up-words/):***

> Source: Teen culture
>   ***Year: - At least 1996***
>   OK to Use: Only if you want to sound like a dude
>
> - Chillax is a combination of chill and relax. Although top Internet search results say chillax originated with the 2003 film Final Destination 2, ***the word actually shows up on the Internet in personal ads going as far back as January 1996 and is included in a musician’s website that includes an Ebonics dictionary with a Google date stamp of February 2, 1996.*** Did anyone really think Hollywood could have created the word on their own?
> - Earliest Known Quotation (film, Final Destination 2, 2003, Spoken by an unnamed kid smoking at a gas pump.) “Chillax, biatch.”
>     Earliest Known Quotation (print, The American Spectator, Volume 36, 2003): “He told me I was overreacting and to ‘chillax.’”

(behindthegrammar.com)